# How do I run a private pub server while still referencing packages from pub.dartlang.org?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Assuming that I'm running my own instance of [`pub-dartlang`](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang)  for a private pub feed; how do I indicate in `pubspec.yaml` which packages come from the private feed vs pub.dartlang.org?

Comment: I'm am trying to do the same thing. How did you make yours private? I would like to limit the users with access to our organization's Google Apps Domain.

Comment: @computmaxer I never actually got around to it; I was just asking for future reference. I was actually just looking for a way to point pub at a private URL, not to apply any authentication. I suspect IP restriction might be the easiest way to do this if the url is public?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `PUB_HOSTED_URL` so it points to your custom pub repo server. This way `pub` loads all packages which don't have a server specified from this server.

You can define exceptions in `pubspec.yaml` like

```yaml
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    hosted:
      name: transmogrify
      url: http://some-package-server.com
```

see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html for more details.

There is another package that seems to provide a custom Pub repo https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_proxy_server

Comment: Awesome; just what I wanted. I checked the `pubspec.yaml` page; didn't spot that one about dependencies :)